# Autofac Lifetime Scope Decorator

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am implementing a command handler pattern using Autofac and am using it's decorator facility handle cross cutting concerns such as logging, authentication etc.

I also have dependencies that I only want scoped to the lifetime of the request / response pipeline.

I have an example implementation below:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(typeof(HandlerModule).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterType<LifetimeScopeTester>().AsSelf()
            .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("pipline");

        var container = builder.Build();

        using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("pipline")) {
            var pingHandler = scope.Resolve<IHandle<PingRequest, PingResponse>>();
            pingHandler.Handle(new PingRequest());
        }
    }
}

public class HandlerModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(ThisAssembly)
            .As(type => type.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(interfaceType => interfaceType.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof (IHandle<,>)))
            .Select(interfaceType => new KeyedService("IHandle", interfaceType)));

        builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
            typeof(SecondDecoratorHandler<,>),
            typeof(IHandle<,>),
            "IHandle"
        )
        .Keyed("SecondDecoratorHandler", typeof(IHandle<,>));

        builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
            typeof(FirstDecoratorHandler<,>),
            typeof(IHandle<,>),
            "SecondDecoratorHandler"
        );
    }
}

public class LifetimeScopeTester {}

public interface IHandle<in TRequest, out TResponse> 
    where TRequest : class, IRequest<TResponse>
{
   TResponse Handle(TRequest request);
}

public interface IRequest<TResponse> {

}

public class PingRequest : IRequest<PingResponse> {

}

public class PingResponse {

}

public class PingHandler : IHandle<PingRequest, PingResponse> {
    public PingResponse Handle(PingRequest request) {
        Console.WriteLine("PingHandler");
        return new PingResponse();
    }
}

public class FirstDecoratorHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IHandle<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : class, IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IHandle<TRequest, TResponse> _decoratedHandler;
    private readonly LifetimeScopeTester _lifetimeScopeTester;

    public FirstDecoratorHandler(IHandle<TRequest, TResponse> decoratedHandler,
        LifetimeScopeTester lifetimeScopeTester)
    {
        _decoratedHandler = decoratedHandler;
        _lifetimeScopeTester = lifetimeScopeTester;
    }

    public TResponse Handle(TRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FirstDecoratorHandler - LifetimeScopeTester[{0}]",
            _lifetimeScopeTester.GetHashCode());
        return _decoratedHandler.Handle(request);
    }
}

public class SecondDecoratorHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IHandle<TRequest, TResponse> 
    where TRequest : class, IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IHandle<TRequest, TResponse> _decoratedHandler;
    private readonly LifetimeScopeTester _lifetimeScopeTester;

    public SecondDecoratorHandler(IHandle<TRequest, TResponse> decoratedHandler, LifetimeScopeTester lifetimeScopeTester)
    {
        _decoratedHandler = decoratedHandler;
        _lifetimeScopeTester = lifetimeScopeTester;
    }

    public TResponse Handle(TRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SecondDecoratorHandler - LifetimeScopeTester[{0}]", _lifetimeScopeTester.GetHashCode());
        return _decoratedHandler.Handle(request);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I wrap the pipleine in a scope named `pipeline` which means that everytime I resolve `LifetimeScopeTester` which is scope to `pipeline`, I get the same instance.

I as thinking that I might be able to replace

```
using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("pipline")) {
    var pingHandler = scope.Resolve<IHandle<PingRequest, PingResponse>>();
    pingHandler.Handle(new PingRequest());
}
```

with

```
var pingHandler = scope.Resolve<IHandle<PingRequest, PingResponse>>();
pingHandler.Handle(new PingRequest());
```

by creating another decorator that does that same thing.

My first instinct was:

```
public class LifetimeScopeDecoratorHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IHandle<TRequest, TResponse> 
    where TRequest : class, IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;
    private readonly IHandle<TRequest, TResponse> _decoratedHandler;

    public LifetimeScopeDecoratorHandlerAttempt1(ILifetimeScope scope, 
        IHandle<TRequest, TResponse> decoratedHandler)
    {
        _scope = scope;
        _decoratedHandler = decoratedHandler;
    }

    public TResponse Handle(TRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LifetimeScopeDecoratorHandler");

        TResponse response;

        using (_scope.BeginLifetimeScope("pipeline"))
        {
            response = _decoratedHandler.Handle(request);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

But the `decoratedHandler` would have already been resolved by the time it's injected so that won't work.

So I tried:

```
public class LifetimeScopeHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IHandle<TRequest, TResponse> 
    where TRequest : class, IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;
    private readonly Func<IHandle<TRequest, TResponse>> _decoratedHandlerFactory;

    public LifetimeScopeHandler(ILifetimeScope scope, 
        Func<IHandle<TRequest, TResponse>> decoratedHandlerFactory)
    {
        _scope = scope;
        _decoratedHandlerFactory = decoratedHandlerFactory;
    }

    public TResponse Handle(TRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LifetimeScopeDecoratorHandler");

        TResponse response;

        using (_scope.BeginLifetimeScope("pipeline"))
        {
            var decoratedHandler = _decoratedHandlerFactory();
            response = decoratedHandler.Handle(request);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

However this repeated infinitely as calling `_decoratedHandlerFactory()` tries to wrap the inner handler with a `LifetimeScopeHandler` decorator again.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible.

I have created a dotnetfiddle at https://dotnetfiddle.net/hwujNI demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `Handle` method of `LifetimeScopeHandler` class invoke the `decoratedHandlerFactory` delegate, it asks *Autofac* to resolve a `IHandle<TRequest, TResponse>` which is a `LifetimeScopeHandler`. That's why you have a `StackOverflowException`. We can simplify your case to this code sample :

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(Func<Foo> fooFactory)
    {
        this._fooFactory = fooFactory;
    }
    private readonly Func<Foo> _fooFactory;

    public void Do()
    {
        Foo f = this._fooFactory();
        f.Do();
    }
}
```

Even if there is a single instance of `Foo` you will have a `StackOverflowException`

In order to resolve this issue, you have to indicate *Autofac* that the `decoratedHandlerFactory` delegate of `LifetimeScopeHandler` should not be a delegate of `LifetimeScopeHandler`.

You can use the `WithParameter` to indicate the last decorator to use a specific parameter :

```
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(LifetimeScopeHandler<,>),
    typeof(IHandle<,>),
    "FirstDecoratorHandler"
)
.WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "decoratedHandlerFactory",
               (pi, c) => c.ResolveKeyed("FirstDecoratorHandler", pi.ParameterType))
.As(typeof(IHandle<,>));
```

With this configuration, the output will be

> LifetimeScopeHandler 
>   FirstDecoratorHandler - LifetimeScopeTester[52243212] 
>   SecondDecoratorHandler - LifetimeScopeTester[52243212] 
>   PingHandler

By the way, you want `LifetimeScopeHandler` to be a special kind of decorator that will create the inner `IHandler<,>` in a special scope.

You can do this by asking the `LifetimeScopeHandler` to create the correct scope for you and resolve the previous `Ihandler`.

```
public class LifetimeScopeHandler<TRequest, TResponse> 
    : IHandle<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : class, IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;

    public LifetimeScopeHandler(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        this._scope = scope;
    }

    public TResponse Handle(TRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LifetimeScopeDecoratorHandler");

        using (ILifetimeScope s = this._scope.BeginLifetimeScope("pipline"))
        {
            var decoratedHandler = 
                s.ResolveKeyed<IHandle<TRequest, TResponse>>("FirstDecoratorHandler");
            TResponse response = decoratedHandler.Handle(request);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation will require that `LifetimeScopeHandler` knows the first decorator on the chain, we can bypass that by sending the name on its constructor.

```
public class LifetimeScopeHandler<TRequest, TResponse> 
    : IHandle<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : class, IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;
    private readonly String _previousHandlerName; 

    public LifetimeScopeHandler(ILifetimeScope scope, String previousHandlerName)
    {
        this._scope = scope;
        this._previousHandlerName = previousHandlerName; 
    }

    public TResponse Handle(TRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LifetimeScopeDecoratorHandler");

        using (ILifetimeScope s = this._scope.BeginLifetimeScope("pipline"))
        {
            var decoratedHandler = 
                s.ResolveKeyed<IHandle<TRequest, TResponse>>(previousHandlerName);
            TResponse response = decoratedHandler.Handle(request);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

And you will have to register it like this :

```
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
         typeof(LifetimeScopeHandler<,>),
         typeof(IHandle<,>),
         "FirstDecoratorHandler"
       )
       .WithParameter("previousHandlerName", "FirstDecoratorHandler")
       .As(typeof(IHandle<,>));
```

We can also bypass everything by not using the `RegisterGenericDecorator` method.

If we register the `LifetimeScopeHandler` like this :

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(LifetimeScopeHandler<,>))
       .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "decoratedHandler",
                      (pi, c) =>
                      {
                          ILifetimeScope scope = c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>();
                          ILifetimeScope piplineScope = scope.BeginLifetimeScope("pipline");
                          var o = piplineScope.ResolveKeyed("FirstDecoratorHandler", pi.ParameterType);
                          scope.Disposer.AddInstanceForDisposal(piplineScope);
                          return o;
                      })
       .As(typeof(IHandle<,>));
```

And `LifetimeScopeHandler` can now look like all decorator :

```
public class LifetimeScopeHandler<TRequest, TResponse> 
  : IHandle<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : class, IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IHandle<TRequest, TResponse> _decoratedHandler;

    public LifetimeScopeHandler(IHandle<TRequest, TResponse> decoratedHandler)
    {
        this._decoratedHandler = decoratedHandler;
    }

    public TResponse Handle(TRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LifetimeScopeDecoratorHandler");

        TResponse response = this._decoratedHandler.Handle(request);
        return response;
    }
}
```

By the way, this solution may have an issue if you use more than one `IHandler<,>` in a scope and you need to have a single `pipline` scope. To resolve this, you can see this dotnetfiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/rQgy2X but it seems to me over complicated and you may not need it.

Comment: Cyril, that solves one problem, however when I did this and removed the `container.BeginLifetimeScope("pipline")` from `Main` I get the following error - `Run-time exception (line 139): No scope with a Tag matching 'pipline' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested.` .. see https://dotnetfiddle.net/u5aMn4

Comment: @kimsagro in your second code sample you are not resolving `IHandle<PingRequest, PingResponse>` from a `pipline` scope but directly from the container. If you resolve it from the correct scope, it works (https://dotnetfiddle.net/fR9mTc).

Comment: I'm confused, the whole point of the `LifetimeScopeHandler` was to wrap the pipeline in a `pipeline` scope so I didn't have to wrap the call from `Main` in a scope

Comment: OK, I better understand your requirements :-). Something like that : https://dotnetfiddle.net/cSgJZ9 but with an open `.InstancePerOwned("FirstDecoratorHandler", typeof(IHandle<PingRequest, PingResponse>))` ...

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue is that I might want to use `LifetimeScopeTester` in multiple handlers, I don't want to register it as `InstancePerOwned("FirstDecoratorHandler", typeof(IHandle<PingRequest, PingResponse>` for each handler. I'm confused as to why the fiddle at https://dotnetfiddle.net/u5aMn4 didn't work?

Comment: `decoratedHandlerFactory` don't come from a `pipline` scope, it comes form the scope used to create a `LifetimeScopeHandler`. Could you use this code sample : https://dotnetfiddle.net/2OSOzk ? If so, I will edit my answer with more explanation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82654/discussion-between-kimsagro-and-cyril-durand).

Comment: Can this work with Evenhandlers as well? multiple eventhandlers listens to the same event!. How can we resolve the right handler given there are many of them ?